# Are there standards or best practices for placing different sized rectangles in a straight line?

Tags: design-principles, spacing

I want to design a letterhead for a technical manual. I think that adding a good letterhead is essential for looking professional. I reviewed a lot of letterhead design but almost all of them do not in my expectation range. So I decided to make my own. I decided to use 3 rectangles with same width and different length. What are the best practices for placing them? I am new to this field. I am open to any suggestions and keywords.

[image]
This is the example that I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Actually any option is valid, the one that best fits the design you are trying to achieve.

What can be given as an answer is some kind of work methodology. In your example there's a detail that appears to be an error, the outer margins are different. This is quite common when thinking about the content and not the container frame. When working on layout design both things are equally important and relevant.

A working methodology is the following:

1. Make the margins guides first.
2. Make two rectangles from the page border to the left margin and from the page border to the right margin.
3. Make the *main rectangle* from margin to margin
4. Make two equal rectangles on top of the *main rectangle* to create the *gaps*
5. Distribute horizontally the margin rectangles and the gaps
6. Group the gaps and move them horizontally right or left

[image: scheme]

[image: animation]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Add also the consideration of "spread" vs "single-page" layout - will this technical manual be printed or online only? If printed, will it be pages facing one another like a book (spreads) or single sheets with only one side printed (single-page)? If it's the more traditional spreads, you need a left-hand and a right-hand version of your letterhead....